# Como alterar a ordem de valores dentro de uma array PHP?

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte array:

```
$arraymaterias=array('his;51','mat;60','mat;60','mat;60','mat;60','mat;32','por;60','por;60','por;60','por;60','por;60','por;60','por;60','por;37');
```

Eu queria que ela intercalasse, para ficar cada hora uma materia, ex:

```
$arraymateriasnova=array('his;51','mat;60','por;60,'mat;60','por;60,'mat;60''por;60','mat;60','por;60','mat;32','por;60','por;60','por;60','por;37');
```

Comment: não entendi? poderia ser mais claro

Comment: Principalmente na parte "ficar cada hora uma materia"

Comment: essa array é montada com um foreach,a cada loop vai pegando todos os valores da materia, então ele monta todos os valores da materia1, depois todos da materia 2, e depois todos da materia 3, eu preciso que ele pegue o 1º valor da materia 1, depois o 1º valor da materaia 2 depois o 1º valor da materia 3, depois o 2º da materia 1(se ainda tiver), 2º da materaia 2 e por ai vai

Comment: Na hora de montar esse `foreach` faça esse remanejamento.